# Magento2 : Overall architecture and achitecture layers

Tags: magento2

I want to more information about it. could you explain or give some references documents or links.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Start here: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/architecture/archi_perspectives/ABasics_intro.html

We plan to update this guide in the near future so watch the space.